# Como remover espaço em branco

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte código

```
var ola = "242 052";
```

Como faço para remover o espaço da variavel? Para que fique por exemplo assim:

```
var ola = "242052";
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Para um espaço:**

```js
var ola = "242 052";

ola = ola.replace(" ","")

console.log(ola);
```

**Mais de um espaço:**

```js
var ola = "242  052";
   
ola = ola.replace( /\s/g, '' )

console.log(ola);
```

O global Match `g`  – procura todas as ocorrências da expressão no texto, ao invés de parar na primeira ocorrência.

```js
var ola = "242  052 098 09            8         7";
   
ola = ola.replace( / /g, '' )

console.log(ola);
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ola = '123 456 789';

ola = ola.split(' ').join('');

console.log(ola);
```